# Convert XML PATH sample code from SQL Server to DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I'm converting the SQL server to db2..
I need a solution for stuff and for xml path

Ex

```
Select stuff(select something 
from table name
Where condition 
For xml path(''),1,1,'')
```

Pls convert this into db2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a do my work for me question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is an old school XML "trick" to convert multiple values to a single string.  (Often comma separated but in this case space separated.)  Since those days DB2 (and the sql standards) have added a new function called listagg which is designed to solve this exact problem:

```
Select listagg(something,' ')
from table name
Where condition
```

db2 docs -

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_listagg.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcollistagg.htm

Comment: @FZs -- did you find that helpful?

Comment: Since the OP used the [db2-400] tag, the more appropriate docs would be [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcollistagg.htm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcollistagg.htm)